# How to create worker process using Otto and Dagger?

Tags: dagger, otto

I want to do some work when certain event happened.

To solve this problem using Android SDK I can create BroadcastReceiver that will start IntentService that will do the job.

Instead of using Android classes I want use normal Java classes to do the same thing.

How can I solve same problem using Otto and Dagger?

Comment: Do you want the work to happen in a different thread than the one that posted the event to the bus?  You said "worker process" in your question - does it need to be a separate process?  Do you want it to happen in a Service, so it can continue running even if the Activity that initiated it is destroyed?